# Java - Image flicker

Tags: java

OK so take a look at this vid (it's 3 seconds long..) showing the problem:

http://www.screenr.com/VbV

See how the images flicker when you first enter the room?

Here's how I have the images set up (they are pulled from `tiles` folder in the .jar file)

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 522; i++) {
tiles[i] = tk.getImage(this.getClass().getResource(String.format("tiles/t%d.png", i)));

                  }
```

and here's how they are painting on:

```
        for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                  int index = board[row][col];
                  g.drawImage(tiles[index], 32 * col, 32 * row, this);

            }
      }
```

How do I stop the flicker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Toolkit.getImage(URL)` method is asynchronous and 522 images might take a 'few moments' to load.  Either add them to a `MediaTracker` or use `ImageIO.read(URL)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Although your code works i think that you havent subclassed to write custom paint() code  etc.. Check this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)

Draw and then display :) It seems nice game though!